# Unable to install gstreamer development packages in redhat/ubi8 docker image

Tags: docker, gstreamer, rhel

I want to install gstreamer library in a Redhat linux docker image. My Dockerfile is as simple as this:

```
FROM redhat/ubi8 AS builder
RUN dnf --disableplugin=subscription-manager -y install gstreamer1-devel gstreamer1-plugins-base-tools gstreamer1-doc gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras gstreamer1-plugins-ugly gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-devel gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to find a match: gstreamer1-devel gstreamer1-plugins-base-tools gstreamer1-doc gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras gstreamer1-plugins-ugly gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-devel gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras
```

According to [this post](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c), I guess I'm doing it right. What else should I do? I want to build a gstreamer-based app inside the container.

Comment: while this Question is off-topic for SO, you may just need to update DNF's cache such that it can find 'em